# How do I read a CSV file into an array using d3js v5

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I am creating a data dashboard that should allow the user to point to a CSV file on their file system, which is then uploaded into the dashboard to perform all kinds of visualisation actions on it.

I am using a nice d3js example for the visualisation, but none of the examples I found include reading the CSV file and I cannot make it work. I can read the CSV file and log the contents to the console, but whatever I do to pass the data into an array (which I can subsequently use as the basic data to visualise), there is simply no way my array becomes available as a JS or even a d3js variable.

Here is part of the file I am using - giving numbers of cars that are in use in various EU countries.

```
Country;Car;Van;Truck;Total
Austria;4748048;375163;78539;5201750
Belgium;5587415;678801;159623;6425839
Croatia;1489338;127395;45757;1662490
```

As the delimiter is a semicolon, I am using the dsv function so that I can explicitly set the delimiter.

```
function getCSVdata( ) {
    var myData = [];
    d3.dsv(";","EU-cars.csv", function(d) {
        return {
            State : d.Country,
            freq: { 
                low  : d.Car,
                med  : d.Van,
                high : d.Truck
            }
        };
    }).then( function(d) {
        myData.push( d );
        console.log( d );
    }); 
    return myData;
}
```

The return value is assigned to a variable named 'freqData' (just using the existing sample code here to try and localise the problem - the used code works file if I declare the object in JS instead of reading it from a CSV file).

Writing the 'freqData' object to my console shows that it is an array with 1 element. Writing 'freqData[0]' to the console shows an array with all expected 26 records. But trying to write 'freqData[0].length' gives an error as that is undefined. Trying to use alert causes an error.

This may be something simple for those who have tons of d3js and other JS experience but it turns out to be too complex for newbies.

I need to use the latest (v5) of d3js, which is using the Promise object that is totally new to me. I cannot figure it out by reading tons of partial info on all kinds of supposedly known methods. If someone can just post a fully working example of reading a CSV and passing the data to a JS object that would be wonderful. I am running out of steam and time.

Thanks

4everJang

Comment: You don't read the CSV file with d3.

Comment: Andrei Gheorghui Gerardo Furtado - This is not helpful. As a newbie in the whole Promise object handling, I cannot possibly know that this d3js method is really the same as asynchronous calls. I had to carefully read the other question a couple of times before it made any connection at all. There is no mention of d3js nor reading CVS files. You could have posted a remark that helps people like me to see the connections, instead of just marking it as a duplicate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run your code you should see that you are indeed loading the data. When I use your example data in a dsv/csv file and run your function I get the following logged to console:

[image]

So it appears as both your load of the dsv file is successful, and your row function is successful, based on the console log in the `then` method.

Let's take a closer look at the `.then` method, this runs after the file has loaded and the row function been applied - or, once the promise has been fulfilled. So the key part here is the `then` method doesn't execute the provided function until after the promise is fulfilled. While we are waiting for the the promise to be fulfilled, code continues to be executed, in your case the return statement executes - *before the data is fully loaded and therefore before the then method executes*. This means you aren't returning any data, and this is your problem.

The simplest and probably most common d3 patterns to fetch the data with your row function is to either place code that requires the loaded data in the .then method's fulfillment function:

```js
function getCSVdata( ) {
    d3.dsv(";","https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Andrew-Reid/SO/master/dsv.csv", function(d) {
        return {
            State : d.Country,
            freq: { 
                low  : d.Car,
                med  : d.Van,
                high : d.Truck
            }
        };
    }).then(function(data) {
      console.log("file has " + data.length + " rows");
      logger(data);
    }); 
}

getCSVdata();

function logger(data) {
 console.log(data);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Or you could take a slightly different form:

```js
function getCSVdata( ) {
    d3.dsv(";","https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Andrew-Reid/SO/master/dsv.csv", function(d) {
        return {
            State : d.Country,
            freq: { 
                low  : d.Car,
                med  : d.Van,
                high : d.Truck
            }
        };
    }).then(fulfilled); 
}

getCSVdata();

function fulfilled(data) {
 // do stuff here:
    console.log(data);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, @andrew-reid. It seems the change in d3js from synchronous to asynchronous calls put me on the wrong footing. I am returning an empty array from getCSVdata() as the Promise was not yet fulfilled. Is there a method to make a sequential piece of code wait for fulfillment without having to place everything in the fulfilled() function?

Comment: @4everJang File loading in D3 has never been synchronous. The means have shifted from `XMLHttpRequest` to Fetch API using promises, but it has always been async! In fact, on the surface there is little change; all code that relies on the loaded data had and still has to be put into a callback which was passed to D3's own methods for version <5 and is as of v5 passed to the promise's `.then()` method. If you want a more *inline* version you might want to have a look into the [`async`-`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) syntax. But beware:

Comment: this is an upcoming feature of ES2017! Although support in major browser as well as Node.js is good you might be better of using a transpiler for now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have not spent enough time on d3js yet, it seems. But I am working on becoming a pro :-)